# Putting my iPhone app on my phone to test?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do I take my working iPhone app and put it on my phone to test with? I dont seem to see how and my googleing doesn't turn up what I think I am looking for...

I am a registered developer and have paid my $99 already.

Would anyone know?

Comment: I would recommend using organiser like Franci suggested.  Its much faster since Xcode automates many of the steps.  However, it might be worth learning the old way Muhammad suggested incase you need to debug issues.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I have already placed the same answer somewhere else for the same question.

There are some steps you need to follow to test your app on your personal iPhone. Below you can find all the steps:

1. Create a MAC certificate at first step.
2. Upload that certificate to developer account.
3. Open developer account at https://developer.apple.com
4. You can now find an option for device id in your developer account on left side.
5. Register your iPhone device.
6. It is time to create your unique identifier on developer account, download your certificate and install it on XCode organize
7. Now open your project and embed your unique identifier in your project.

These steps can be beneficial for all software testing gusy involved in mobile application testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register as an Apple developer. This will cost you $99/year.

That is the only way that I know of apart from Jailbreaking your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode Organizer window and provision your device for development. This will register the device UID with Apple and install the development provisioning profile on it. If you don't have provisioning profile, Xcode will create one automatically.

Once this is done, you need to set your build to use your DEV cert to aign your app. Then you can switch the build configuration from Simulator to Device and build and run on your phone.

Comment: I have a Developer Profile identity and a team provisioning profile already. I set to my target to Device-4.1 | Release | and build no, errors, but I dont see the app on my phone or an .ipa file anyplace in any of my Build folders....

Comment: There are videos on the iPhone Provisioning Portal site. There are also help pages available in the How To tab in the provisioning section. These are very helpful.

Comment: Just building is not deploying the app automatically. You have to Build and Run or Build and Debug to make Xcode deploy to the device.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you just complie your project or you complied and Run? If you Build your project and you have no errors it means everything it's ok. The next step is to Build and Run your project or just Run your project.
- If you Run your project and nothing happens it means that you have something worn in your target configuration. Did you change anything there? In the Project Tab in your XCode go to Edit Active Target Settings and check that your Base SDK and Target SDK match your iDevice SDK.
- IF you don't find out what the problem is, contact me, i could help you in anything you need.